# Changing the default value in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to update the existing default value for one of the columns in a table.

> table name: TRANSACTIONS
>
> column name :CURRENCY   current default
>
> value: not available   new current default value : NA

Can someone please let me know how I can update the existing default value to the new default value.

I tried using the below statments but they do not work for me:

```
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ALTER COLUMN CURRENCY SET DEFAULT 'NA';

ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ADD CURRENCY varchar(256) DEFAULT 'NA';

ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS MODIFY COLUMN CURRENCY VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA';

ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS CHANGE COLUMN CURRENCY CURRENCY VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA';

alter table TRANSACTIONS alter column CURRENCY set default 'NA';
```

Comment: Seems like a bad choice of default value. What's wrong with NULL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify Default value in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547210/modify-default-value-in-sql-server)

Comment: Defaults are constraints. Possible duplicate of [altering DEFAULT constraint on column SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363386/altering-default-constraint-on-column-sql)

Comment: DEFAULT is a CONSTRAINT, drop it by name and recreate again

Comment: If my answer helped, then please mark as the answer. If it didn't, then let me know why and I'll try to help some more! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the default value constraint then recreate:

```
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS DROP CONSTRAINT DF_TRANSACTIONS_CURRENCY
GO
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TRANSACTIONS_CURRENCY DEFAULT ('NA') FOR CURRENCY
GO
```

You may have to change "DF_TRANSACTIONS_CURRENCY" to the name of your current constraint if it's different.