# How do I find out a constraint name in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have been trying recently to change the default value of a column as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547210/modify-default-value-in-sql-server). The solution I found there requires deleting the default constraint, which requires knowing the name of that constraint.

The problem I am having is that I do not know how to find out the constraint name in MariaDB. In the same post, these solutions were suggested:

```sql
SELECT NAME FROM sys.default_constraints WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable');

sp_help MyTable

sp_helpconstraint MyTable
```

All of these produce syntax errors in MariaDB, since they all seem to be for MSSQL or MySQL.

So, what do I need to do to find out the constraint name?

Comment: Please check the link for the information schemas - system tables that has details of the tables. [schema tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-tables/).  I see tables like CONSTRAINT, CHECK_CONSTRAINTS and REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS. Search in there.

Comment: [Alter Table - default value](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/altering-tables-in-mariadb/)  This page has the sql to change the default value. See if that helps.

Comment: @praveen thanks, that is exactly what I needed to do! I'm not really sure how I didn't end up finding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints are shown in the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table-name>` along with everything else that relates to a table.