# Sequelize with SQL Server migration alter column error

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I am facing an issue in sequelize sync when alter: true with MySQL connection

```
node :- 14.X
mssql :- 2018
sequalize : v6
```

Case:

model: userAuthSettings has a default value and I have started the app a second time **sequalize migration is alter:true**

Error:

> Executing (default): ALTER TABLE [userAuthSettings] ALTER COLUMN [loginRetryLimit] INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>
> node-app     | /home/node/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/query.js:314
> node-app     |     return new sequelizeErrors.DatabaseError(err);
> node-app     |            ^
> node-app     |
> node-app     | DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.

NOTE: I know it is sequelize issue but does anyone have a solution?

I need a solution in sequalize orm, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Covered in [Changing default value with changeColumn does not work in SQL Server #7403](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7403) which references [Modify Default value in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15547375/390122) and [How do you drop a default value or similar constraint in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124357/390122) The fix is to remove the existing constraint and then add a replacement.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this error is generated by sequalize orm , i know the right query but is there any solution to get out from this because it is SEQUALIZE ORM issue